# php code to generate unique coupon no in every receipt

Tags: php

below is my code ...is it possible for you..to generate max+1 from temp. entered no.

i post my code...i need is loop code start from 500 then insert value in receipt_no column like 500,501,502,503 upto reached

```
     for($row1=$bookcode;$row1<=$Temp_book;$row1++) 
{   for($row=500;$row<=510;$row++) {    
$query = $database->getRow("SELECT MAX(receipt_no) AS max1 FROM scheme_master;"); $largestNumber = $query['max1']; $top = $largestNumber + 1;
    $insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO scheme_master (book_no2,receipt_no,created) VALUES (:book_no2,:receipt_no,:created)", 
array(':receipt_no'=>$row,':book_no2'=>$row1,':created'=>$created)); 
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number doesn't matter as long as it's unique, why not consider using the built in PHP function [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)?

If it does matter, and you would like them sequential, you should use a transaction-based MySQL query and pull them from an auto-incrementing table. (Use transactions so the table is locked during the query, guarantees you get your number and it increments before another tries to get theirs)

EDIT: Modified Code

```
$receipt_no = $_POST['receipt_no'];                     
$coupon = $_POST['coupon'];     

$Temp_receipt =  $receipt_no;                   
$Temp_coupon =   $coupon;

for($row=1;$row<=$Temp_receipt;$row++)
{                           
    for($row2=1;$row2<=$Temp_coupon;$row2++)
    {   
        echo "Coupon #: ".uniqid();
    }
}
```

Comment: below is my code ...is it possible for you..to generate max+1 from temp. entered no.

Comment: for($row1=$bookcode;$row1<=$Temp_book;$row1++)
     {       
     for($row=500;$row<=510;$row++)
      {          
       $query = $database->getRow("SELECT MAX(receipt_no) AS max1 FROM scheme_master;");
       $largestNumber = $query['max1'];
       $top = $largestNumber + 1;                     
        $insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO scheme_master (book_no2,receipt_no,created)
         VALUES (:book_no2,:receipt_no,:created)", 
        array(':receipt_no'=>$row,':book_no2'=>$row1,':created'=>$created));
        
      }}}

Comment: i post my code...i need is loop code start from 500 then insert value in receipt_no column like 500,501,502,503  upto reached